# Is there a possibility to convert IDN to ACE in ORACLE using regex_replace for email addresses

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a regular expression to convert email addresses witch Internationalized Domain Names to Ascii Converted Expressions

from
jürgen@müller.de (IDN)
to
xn--jrgen-kva@xn--mller-kva.com (ACE)

```
select regex_replace(email, IDN, ACE) from dual
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Java is enabled inside the database, then you can wrap the `java.net.IDN` class inside a function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION IDN_TO_ASCII( idn IN NVARCHAR2 ) RETURN VARCHAR2
AS LANGUAGE JAVA NAME 'java.net.IDN.toASCII(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String';
/
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT IDN_TO_ASCII(N'jürgen@müller.de') AS ACE FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ACE |
> | --- |
> | xn--jrgen@mller-thbg.de |

Or:

```sql
SELECT IDN_TO_ASCII(N'jürgen') || '@' || IDN_TO_ASCII(N'müller.de') AS ACE
FROM   DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ACE |
> | --- |
> | xn--jrgen-kva@xn--mller-kva.de |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b70f866c11c9b1c06c26da8761f74630)*